# Kendo UI Observable calculated property how to force change notification

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, observable

In cases using Kendo UI Observable (MVVM) for HTML element binding I occasionally use calculated values, but I can't find a way to force the binding to update when the dependent values change. A simple example:

```
<div id="test3">
    1. <span data-bind="text: addr"></span><br />
    2. <span data-bind="text: addr1"></span><br />
    3. <span data-bind="text: addr2"></span><br />
</div>

<script>
    viewModel = kendo.observable({
        addr1: "",
        addr2: "",
        addr: function () {
            return this.addr1 + ' ' + this.addr2;
        },
        load: function () {
            this.set("addr1", "123 Main St");
            this.set("addr2", "STE 101");

            //need to let view model know to update addr binding
        }
    });

    //to demonstrate the problem of notification bind here
    kendo.bind($("#test3"), viewModel);

    viewModel.load();

    //if I bind here it works, of course
    //kendo.bind($("#test3"), viewModel);

</script>
```

I have a work-around for this where I set the 'addr' element directly, but that defeats the point of data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your addr function to use the 'get' function to retrieve the values:

```
addr: function () {
    return this.get("addr1") + ' ' + this.get("addr2");
},
```

The 'get' function is part of the kendo observable framework. When used like this, kendo will then know to refresh the bound value from your function when any of the values within it, accessed via 'get', are 'set' elsewhere.

Comment: Yep, that did it, brilliant!